# BigInteger implementation of RSA's key generation

Tags: java, rsa, biginteger

I am having a bit of trouble getting the modulus's size to be consistently 128 bytes big. Sometimes the modulus's byte array has a size of 129 or even 130. I've searched for implementation online, and my implementation is really close to the one from this link: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/78crypto/RSA.java.html

Here is my implementation:

```
public static void genKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    int bitLength = 512;
    SecureRandom srand = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger one  = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitLength, srand);
    BigInteger q = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitLength, srand);
    BigInteger phi = (p.subtract(one)).multiply(q.subtract(one));

    BigInteger modulus    = p.multiply(q); //Varies here                                  
    BigInteger publicKey  = new BigInteger("65537");     
    BigInteger privateKey = publicKey.modInverse(phi);

    byte[] modulusArray = modulus.toByteArray();
    byte[] publicKeyArray = publicKey.toByteArray();
    byte[] privateKeyArray = privateKey.toByteArray();
    byte[] tmpArray = new byte[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < publicKeyArray.length; i++) {
        tmpArray[i] = publicKeyArray[i];
    }
    publicKeyArray = tmpArray;
    byte[] publicKeyAndModulus = concat(modulusArray, publicKeyArray);
    byte[] privateKeyAndModulus = concat(modulusArray, privateKeyArray);
}
```

In addition, the privateKey length would vary a bit too. Can I get more consistency with the size using java.Security library or is this not possible to achieve?

Comment: A `BigInteger` implementation of RSA would be really slow; why not use BouncyCastle? In fact, **please** use [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).

Comment: I was thinking of that. However, I need to store the modulus along with the keys in file. How are the key pairs stored in PublicKey and PrivateKey? Can I obtain the modulus value through PublicKey and PrivateKey?

Comment: You generally create a [`AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/AsymmetricCipherKeyPair.html). This [blog post](http://ox.no/posts/rsa-using-bouncycastle) gives an example.

Comment: I hope this is only for academic purposes. Raw RSA is horribly insecure, you would have to implement a secure padding like OAEP or simply use the one provided by Java's Cipher class.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sorry, I mistyped there. The actual code has 512 value. Yes this is only for study purposes.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Your link helped me greatly. I also figured out why I am having an extra value in the byte array. Its because toByteArray returns a two's complement form and sometimes this includes a zero in the beginning of the array. I would gladly accept your comment as an answer if you're willing to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) and create an [`AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/AsymmetricCipherKeyPair.html); here is an example I adapted from [RSA using BouncyCastle](http://ox.no/posts/rsa-using-bouncycastle)

```
public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair generateKeys(int keySizeInBits) {
    RSAKeyPairGenerator kpg = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
    kpg.init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), keySizeInBits));
    return kpg.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`BigInteger#bitLength()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength%28%29) function has the necessary documentation:

> Returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this BigInteger, *excluding* a sign bit.

When you generate a BigInteger with `bitLength` 512, the most significant bit will be 0 ~50% of the time in which case the sign bit will take its place and it will fit into 64 bytes, but in the other cases the most significant bit will be 1 which means that the sign bit will be put into a new byte.

This means that using 511 as the `bitLength` always results BigIntegers of 64 bytes and 128 bytes for the modulus.

You shouldn't really generate `p`, `q`, the modulus and all the other values yourself. It is best to use existing APIs such as Java's [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class which also provides proper padding to be used with RSA such as OAEP (PKCS#1 v1.5 is not good anymore): "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding".